# Making a timestamp from 01-01-0001 to a given date/time

Tags: php, api, date, time, filemaker

I have got an issue in which I am using the FileMaker PHP API which interacts with the FileMaker platform from the web.

My Issue is that the FileMaker Platform does not use the typical epoch but instead it uses a timestamp from 01-01-0001

Is there anyway to create a function which will generate a timestamp from 01-01-0001 to date('now'), for example?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps. I do understand PHP just fyi so I'm not a total newbie at PHP.

Comment: Deleted my answer, sorry misread your Q. The seconds from year 1 would be a massive number? I guess you could add on 1970 years worth of seconds onto your normal timestamps...

Comment: It generate number of seconds from Christ epoch?

Comment: How are you actually getting the 01-01-0001 value from FileMaker? FileMaker will typically return dates and timestamps as formatted date/timestamp values, not seconds since the (FileMaker) epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to get a PHP timestamp from a FileMaker  timestamp. If this is correct, you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on the data returned to you by the FileMaker PHP API.

```
// Code that sets $record to a FileMaker_Record object
$timstamp = strtotime( $record->getField( 'timestamp_field' ) );
```

If, on the other hand, you have a PHP timestamp an need to convert it to a FileMaker timestamp, you can use the `date` function with a format string as pointed out by [Tim Dietrich](http://filemakeraddict.blogspot.com/2009/07/setting-filemaker-timestamp-fields-from.html).

```
$user_update_request = $fm->newEditCommand('PHP_Users', $user->getRecordID());
$user_update_request->setField('Last_Login', date("m/d/Y h:i:s A"));
$user_update_result = $user_update_request->execute();
```

Comment: Sorry about the late acceptance, I've been on paternity leave and I haven't checked SO lately. thanks though, it is what I needed.